# ASP.NET Impersonation with Elevation

Tags: asp.net, uac, impersonation

I have an ASP.NET application configured via `web.config` to use impersonation like this:

```
<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
```

The application needs to perform certain administrative tasks. This works fine if I'm logged on to the application as user `administrator`, but won't work (access to administrative-only system resources fails) when logged in as, say, `userA`, which *does* have administrative access on the system.

I suspect what's happening here is `UAC` is stepping in. Although the ASP.NET app is impersonating `userA`, when it comes to performing something requiring elevation, it fails, whereas running as `administrator` is fine, since that user starts out elevated (never gets a UAC prompt if performing actions interactively in Windows).

Incidentally, I don't need network-level impersonation, so I don't believe I should need `delegation`?

Comment: "The application needs to perform certain administrative tasks" - What are the tasks? "which does have administrative access on the system" -is that user `userA` in Local Administrators group of that machine?

Comment: *"What are the tasks?"* - Reading and writing files in system directories. *"Is `userA` in local administrators group of that machine?"* - Yes, or in some situations it will be in a domain group. I'm happy enough to limit that requirement to the local admin group only.

Comment: I've just discovered that this only seems to be the case if my browser is on the same machine as IIS, and I'm attempting to log in as the same user I'm logged into Windows as. I guess it's detecting I have an interactive login session and wanting to throw up a UAC prompt. But if I'm on a separate machine, UAC is bypassed. Interestingly, in *most* (but not quite all) cases, running the browser as admin resolves the issue, presumably because it's "pre-elevating" the UAC.

Comment: But now on another server, even when running the browser on a separate machine, the issue occurs. *baffled*

Comment: Did you ever find a solution

Comment: @zaitsman I did not.

Answer (score 0):

Our company messed with an in house application and UAC for over two weeks. We took two approaches to the issue.

First, we created a security group and security policies, created a user and assigned the web application pool to run as that user. That got around just some of our issues.

When that didn't fix all of our issues, and we couldn't get the application fixed to work with the permissions we could give it... we turned off UAC on that server. This is by far a *huge* security risk, and some places this won't be acceptable. But, we could get the administrator tokens we needed for some of the tasks that needed to be completed.

I doubt that it's possible to have the application pool present an UAC authentication box to a desktop user, because of the sandbox services are given. If it applies, you may want to a sysadmin/IT department involved and talk about the risks, and benefits of different approaches.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experiences Steven, those are some *alternatives* to explore, but I'm holding on to hope that there's a more direct solution.

Comment: I'm keeping an eye on this question as well, because I'd **love** to revisit the situation.